# GitHub enterprise login using curl

Tags: github-api

Hi I am trying to login into GitHub enterprise using curl for internal purposes. I use following command to fetch list of url information:

```
curl -u "xplorebitshq" https://api.github.com
```

I have Github enterprise url. So, i tried to login into GitHub enterprise by replacing the "https://api.github.com" with "https://github.kdc.capitalone.com".

```
curl -u "enterpriseuser" https://github.kdc.capitalone.com
```

I am getting following error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: github.kdc.capitalone.com
```

What do I need or changed in command to login and fetch list of repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub enterprise [API URL is](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/):

```
http(s)://hostname/api/v3/
```

But in your case, the domain itself (`github.kdc.capitalone.com`) is not resolved by the DNS.

One reason for that (which is not related to the API URL at all) is if you are working behind a proxy.

Don't forget to set a NO_PROXY (or no_proxy) environment variable

```
set no_proxy=.capitalone.com,localhost,::1
```

That would avoid any https query to pass by the proxy for a locally accessible network domain.